# How to make the Telegram bot inline cache be case sensitive?

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm making a Telegram bot for fun (@zeroxisbot), and I have ran into an issue. I have a inline command "wacky", that changes the text you put in, and does it differently if it starts with a uppercase or lowercase letter. So, here's how I expect it to work:

```
@zeroxisbot test -> tEst
@zeroxisbot Test -> TeSt
```

It sort of works, but if I test these two one after another, the second one returns the same thing as the first one.

What I think is happening is that Telegram is caching this query and returning it directly without talking to my bot. But when it loads that cache it doesn't test for case sensitivity, and so even though it is different (starts with uppercase) it returns the old lowercase one. After some minutes, I can test it again and it does seem to reset, because the cache is being cleared.

So, is there any way that I can make the cache be case sensitive? And if not, is there any way that I can disable that cache so it always goes directly to my bot?

I'm using python-telegram-bot by the way.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the [cache_time](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.inlinequery.html?highlight=cache_time) parameter of telegram.InlineQuery.answer

> **cache_time** (*int*, *optional*) – The maximum amount of time in seconds that the result of the inline query may be cached on the server. Defaults to 300.

Example:

```
def inlinequery(update, context):
    query = update.inline_query.query
    results = [
        InlineQueryResultArticle(
            id=uuid4(),
            title="time",
            input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(
                "time: {!s}".format(time.asctime(time.localtime()))))
        ]
    seconds = 30;
    update.inline_query.answer(results,cache_time=seconds)
```

Now the answer will be cached for 30 seconds.

If you want different cache_time for different queries, you should make a `update.inline_query.answer(results,cache_time=seconds)` for every query you accept and not a single one for every query you receive (my example does the latter).